# Can i SELECT two user names by id in another table with join?

Tags: mysql

I have table sb_bans which including `BannerID` and `UnbannerID`.
And another one `sb_admins` which including `aid` and `name`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT sb_bans.*, sb_admins.authid as admin_authid, sb_admins.user as admin_name
FROM sb_bans 
LEFT JOIN sb_admins 
ON sb_admins.aid = sb_bans.aid 
ORDER BY `sb_bans`.`bid`
```

Table `sb_bans` look like this:

```
| bid | BannerID | UnbannerID |
|=====|==========|============|
|  1  |    26    |     26     |
|  2  |    27    |     13     |
|  3  |    10    |     13     |
|  4  |    11    |     27     |
|  5  |    13    |     10     |
```

Table `sb_admins` look like this:

```
| aid |   name   |
|=====|==========|
| 10  | Tomi     |
| 11  | Dominik  |
| 13  | Michal   |
| 26  | Kristian |
| 27  | Daniel   |
```

And i want make `SELECT` what will look like:

```
| bid | BannerID | UnbannerID |
|=====|==========|============|
|  1  | Kristian | Kristian   |
|  2  | Daniel   | Michal     |
|  3  | Tomi     | Michal     |
|  4  | Dominik  | Daniel     |
|  5  | Michal   | Tomi       |
```

I only know how to make it when i want use `name` by `aid` only once.
It is how i have it in my quary code upper.
Please can someone help me configure SQL code to make it work well.
Thanks so mutch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL, see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sjtJBAccd4gvZYZChbuWmx/1

```
create table sb_bans (
bid     int,
bannerid int,
unbannerid int
);

create table sb_admins (
aid int,
name varchar(10)
);

insert into sb_bans values (1,26,26);
insert into sb_bans values (2,27,13);
insert into sb_bans values (3,10,13);
insert into sb_bans values (4,11,27);
insert into sb_bans values (5,13,10);

insert into sb_admins values (10, 'Tomi');
insert into sb_admins values (11, 'Dominik');
insert into sb_admins values (13, 'Michal');
insert into sb_admins values (26, 'Kristian');
insert into sb_admins values (27, 'Daniel');

select b.bid,
       s.name as banner_id,
       s1.name as unbannerid
  from sb_bans b
  join sb_admins s
    on b.bannerid = s.aid
  join sb_admins s1
    on b.unbannerid = s1.aid
```

Comment: Sorry MYSQL. It will select from same db when i put after it 1 ?

Comment: Oh i understand it i go try it.

Comment: Ok hope that helps.

Comment: OK, It work well thanks you so mutch.